# external CSS files are not loading all the time in IE 11. But when i hard refresh the page its loading. how to fix this issue?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

**external CSS files are not loading all the time in IE 11**. But when I hard refresh the page its loading. Is there any way to ensure External CSS files load properly in IE 11 browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<ui:composition>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/css/css-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="path/to/CSS" />
```

this is how I included CSS files.

Comment: What do the browser tools tell you?  As reference, IE is not longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 0):

If a hard refresh will make them work, that means your external CSS files are getting cached in the browser and they may not get updated from time to time. You can try specifying the version number of a style sheet to force the browser to update CSS. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css?version=2">
```